# How to call NVIDIA Performance Primitives from python?

Tags: python, nvidia, npp

Is there a way to call [NVIDIA Performance Primitives](https://developer.nvidia.com/npp) library (NPP) from `python`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about NPP in python, but instead you can use CuPy python library which is pretty convenient and efficient.